# How to sort an array of arrays by a specified element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays, each array within the array is set up like this

```
[1, firstname, lastname, 22]
```

I have a total of 12 of these, I am trying to sort the arrays by the 4th element of each array in descending order but nothing I have tried has worked, namely I have been trying to do array.sort with a comparison function and having look at the 4th element in each array but cant get it to work. Here is what I currently have:

```
function sortArray (a, b){
    return a-b;
}

for (var k = 0; k<employeeArray.length; k++){
    var j = k-1;
    employeeArray.sort(sortArray([k][3],[j][3]));
}
```

What I was expecting was for the function to sort the arrays by the 4th element but it keeps throwing up Uncaught Type errors.

Comment: You're passing a *numeric value* to `sort`.  You need to pass a *function* which returns such a numeric value.  Something like `employeeArray.sort((a, b) => b[3] - a[3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on [how sort works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

---

The `.sort` method handles the sorting. You do not need a `for-loop`.

Instead, you need to make your function sort two entries properly:

```
function sortTwoArrays(a, b){
    return a[3] - b[3];
}
```

Now you can just pass this as the parameter to the `.sort` method of your `employeeArray`:

```
employeeArray.sort(sortTwoArrays);
```

which will modify the array.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: @Ryan Please accept then!